# Infinite series and product

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, infinite-product

I ended up having the infinite product

$$
A=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1+a_n)
$$

for $a_n$ a positive series. What I would like to do is show that this is convergent. On the other hand I have the sum

$$
B=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n
$$

Is it true that $A$ and $B$ both converge or both diverge?
Thanks

Comment: What do you think about it?

Comment: The answer is YES. Take logarithms and use the fact that $\ln (1+x) \sim x$ as $x \to 0$.